# How to combine 2 separate angular projects to the same node API?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, mean, angular7-router

My problem is I am build a Web Application, I have done the normal Front End work separately as an Angular 7 project and I have done the Admin Panel controlling the Web App separately so now I am having 2 Angular Apps and 1 Node.js app has the APIs

What I am trying to do is making the Front End design at www.domain.com and the Admin Panel at admin.domain.com

I have been looking around too much but didn't find a proper solution fixing my issue yet

Also if I am trying to do isn't the best solution, then what is the best solution?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about your issue

Comment: Just mentioned all details above  simply I am having 2 angular apps fully working on local server but how to publish them to keep one on a sub domain and one on domain

Comment: This is more of a hosting issue not a programming issue.